# Using Kafka for batch job replacement

Tags: apache-kafka

I am newbie with Kafka. Want to explore possibility of using Kafka to replace our batch job system currently in place.
Current system:
We get lots of feeds  EVERYDAY in flat files (CSVs, JSONs,TXTs and binary) from external vendors using FTPS, SFTP, Emails, fileshare etc.  I am ashamed to say that currently all logic resides in stored procedures and vbscript. I am trying to modernize whole pipeline using Apache Kafka to ingest all these feeds. I have explored Kafka and found that I can use Kafka Connect and KSQL and SpoolDir connector for this purpose however  I am not very clear on how to go about this.

*Question*:
I want to device system wherein I am able to ingest all incoming flat files (flat files mentioned earlier) using Kafka. I got that we can use Kafka connectors and KSQL or Streaming APIs to achiev this. Part I am not clear is how do I turn it into repetitive task using Kafka. Like every morning I get flat file feed in specific folder, how do I automate this process using Kafka like scheduling reading of files at specific time of day and every day? Do I need any kind of service (windows service or cron job) to constantly keep eye on folder to watch incoming files and process it? Is there any reasonable solution to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminder that Kafka is not meant for file transfers. You can ingest data about the files (locations and sizes, for example, or extract data from them to produce rather than whole files), but you'll want to store and process their full contents elsewhere

Spooldir connector will work for local filesystems, but not over FTP. For that, there's another `kafka-connect-fs` project

However, I generally recommend combining Apache Nifi ListenFTP processors with ProduceKafka actions for something like this.

Nifi also has Email (IMAP/POP3) and NFS/Samba (fileshare) getters that can be scheduled, and it'll handle large files much better than Kafka.

KSQL and Streams API only work once the data is in Kafka

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. If I use SpoolDir connector for local filesystem, will it continuously listen to source folder for any new file arrivals or do I need to have some program to keep eye on folder to watch for new files?

Comment: The Connector process runs as a daemon, and should watch for new files. MiNiFi project can also be installed and process/ship those files to a NiFi cluster process.

Comment: Can NiFi read those files on its own or we will have to use MiNiFi as welll?

Comment: Think of Nifi as the central dashboard for managing the cluster. Minifi is the remote, lightweight agent that does some work. You can install a full Nifi node where you want to read files, but I'd recommend not overloading the file servers since those are critical pieces of your system